# Listing text falls outside of box in itemize environment

Tags: listings

I am attempting to have a listing inside of an enumerate environment, however, the text falls outside of the box like this:

[image]

Can you tell me how to adjust the text or widen the framed box so that the text appears correctly?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
language=Pascal
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an example
\noindent
\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,width=6in]{\bfseries{vpasolve for $\mathbf{f(y)}$}}
syms y
vpasolve((1.2*y)*(1-(y/15)) - (4*y)/(0.5+y) == 0, y)
\end{mylisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should read some questions about line breaks in listings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version with linebreak. It has to use an own style, because you probably don't want to decrease the line width for all of your listings (outside from tcolorboxes).

[image: listing]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
language=Pascal,
}

\lstdefinestyle{mytcbstyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
language=Pascal,
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
linewidth=.8\linewidth
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mytcbstyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an example
\noindent
\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow,width=6in]{\bfseries{vpasolve for $\mathbf{f(y)}$}}
syms y
vpasolve((1.2*y)*(1-(y/15)) - (4*y)/(0.5+y) == 0, y)
\end{mylisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  Is there a solution to possibly shift the text closer to the left side of the box instead so that the text will fit inside the box?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe You could try `left=1pt` or any length you find appropriate as option to `newtcblisting`.

Comment: Thanks, that apparently did not work as expected.  Although the text shifted, there was still some fallout.  I then tried to increase the box width `width = 5cm`, but that did not work.  How then to increase the box width?

Comment: @Joe Use `text width`, but that will probably go to the right. Your problem seems to be specific to listings, because the internal `lstlisting` will have a left margin (you should look it up in its documentation).

Answer (score 3):

Loading `enumitem` and using the `wide` option for `enumerate` seems to solve the problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe, enumitem}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\small,
numbersep=8pt,
language=Pascal
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt,
    listing only,
    listing style=mystyle,
    title=#2,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item This is an example
\begin{mylisting}[hbox,enhanced,drop shadow]{\bfseries{vpasolve for $\mathbf{f(y)}$}}
syms y
vpasolve((1.2*y)*(1-(y/15)) - (4*y)/(0.5+y) == 0, y)
\end{mylisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Can this be made local to one specific item?  I have other enumerate blocks and other `items`.  Your solution is the closest that seems to satisfy my requirement, however, it is affecting the layout of the other enumerate environments.  Can your solution be tailored to just that specific `item`?  Thanks again!

Comment: It is very easy: you can close the `enumerate` environment right after this item, and open immediately a new one with option `resume` which will start the counter from the previous one. See details in the `enumitem` documentation.

Comment: Thank you!  Is there an easy option however to increase the width of the box itself without affecting anything else?  I tried `width = 5cm`, but that had no effect.  Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know very well `tcolorbox`, but my first idea – temporarily increasing the right margin – doesn't work. I'll to try to  see the details for `tcbox` widths later.